# Sequelize many to many belongsToMany issue in NodeJS

Tags: javascript, node.js, sequelize.js

I am trying to create many-to-many relations between roles and accesses. `roles` table will have a list of roles(admin, developer etc...) and `accesses` table will have a list of permissions(Create Project, Create Site, Delete Project etc...). I am trying to make many-to-many relations and create a junction table as RolePermissions.

Now I have created all the migrations and created tables successfully, But when I start the node server I am betting below error in Sequelize **index.js**.

I spent couple hours not able to get it, please some one suggest me... Thanks in Advance.

```js
C:\Users\chand\Work\AssetOne\AI-app\ai-application-service\node_modules\sequelize\src\associations\belongs-to-many.js:136
      this.targetKeyField = this.target.rawAttributes[this.targetKey].field || this.targetKey;        
                                                                      ^
TypeError: Cannot read property 'field' of undefined
    at new BelongsToMany (C:\Users\chand\Work\AssetOne\AI-app\ai-application-service\node_modules\sequelize\src\associations\belongs-to-many.js:136:71)
    at Function.belongsToMany (C:\Users\chand\Work\AssetOne\AI-app\ai-application-service\node_modules\sequelize\src\associations\mixin.js:64:25)
    at Function.associate (C:\Users\chand\Work\AssetOne\AI-app\ai-application-service\models\access-list.js:13:18)
    at C:\Users\chand\Work\AssetOne\AI-app\ai-application-service\models\index.js:36:19
    at Array.forEach (<anonymous>)
    at Object.<anonymous> (C:\Users\chand\Work\AssetOne\AI-app\ai-application-service\models\index.js:34:17)
    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1085:14)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1114:10)
    at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:950:32)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:790:12)
```

Sequlize versions:

```
**"sequelize-cli": "^6.6.0",** 
**"sequelize": "^6.31.0",**
```

**index.js**

```js
'use strict';

const fs = require('fs');
const path = require('path');
const Sequelize = require('sequelize');
const basename = path.basename(__filename);
const env = process.env.NODE_ENV || 'development';
const config = require(__dirname + '/../config/config.js')[env];
const db = {};

let sequelize;
if (config.use_env_variable) {
  sequelize = new Sequelize(process.env[config.use_env_variable], {
    ...config,
    dialectModule: require('mysql2')
  });
} else {
  sequelize = new Sequelize(config.database, config.username, config.password, {
    ...config,
    dialectModule: require('mysql2')
  });
}

fs
  .readdirSync(__dirname)
  .filter((file) => {
    return (file.indexOf('.') !== 0) && (file !== basename) && (file.slice(-3) === '.js');
  })
  .forEach((file) => {
    const model = require(path.join(__dirname, file))(sequelize, Sequelize.DataTypes);
    db[model.name] = model;
  });

Object.keys(db).forEach(modelName => {
  if (db[modelName].associate) {
    db[modelName].associate(db); // Here I am getting error
  }
});

db.sequelize = sequelize;
db.Sequelize = Sequelize;

module.exports = db
```

**role-list-migration.js**

```js
'use strict';
/** @type {import('sequelize-cli').Migration} */
module.exports = {
  async up(queryInterface, Sequelize) {
    await queryInterface.createTable('RoleLists', {
      name: {
        allowNull: false,
        primaryKey: true,
        type: Sequelize.STRING
      },
      createdAt: {
        allowNull: false,
        type: Sequelize.DATE
      },
      updatedAt: {
        allowNull: false,
        type: Sequelize.DATE
      }
    });
  },
  async down(queryInterface, Sequelize) {
    await queryInterface.dropTable('RoleLists');
  }
};
```

**permission-migration.js**

```
'use strict';
/** @type {import('sequelize-cli').Migration} */
module.exports = {
  async up(queryInterface, Sequelize) {
    await queryInterface.createTable('AccessLists', {
      id: {
        allowNull: false,
        autoIncrement: true,
        primaryKey: true,
        type: Sequelize.INTEGER
      },
      access: {
        type: Sequelize.STRING
      },
      createdAt: {
        allowNull: false,
        type: Sequelize.DATE
      },
      updatedAt: {
        allowNull: false,
        type: Sequelize.DATE
      }
    });
  },
  async down(queryInterface, Sequelize) {
    await queryInterface.dropTable('AccessLists');
  }
};
```

**role-permissions-migrations.js**

```
'use strict';
/** @type {import('sequelize-cli').Migration} */
module.exports = {
  async up(queryInterface, Sequelize) {
    await queryInterface.createTable('RolePermissions', {
      id: {
        allowNull: false,
        autoIncrement: true,
        primaryKey: true,
        type: Sequelize.INTEGER
      },
      role_name: {
        type: Sequelize.STRING,
        onDelete: 'CASCADE',
        references: {
          model: "RoleLists",
          key: "name",
          as: 'role_name'
        }
      },
      access_id: {
        type: Sequelize.INTEGER,
        onDelete: 'CASCADE',
        references: {
          model: "AccessLists",
          key: "id"
        }
      },
      createdAt: {
        allowNull: false,
        type: Sequelize.DATE
      },
      updatedAt: {
        allowNull: false,
        type: Sequelize.DATE
      }
    });
  },
  async down(queryInterface, Sequelize) {
    await queryInterface.dropTable('RolePermissions');
  }
};
```

**role-model.js**

```js
'use strict';
const {
  Model
} = require('sequelize');
module.exports = (sequelize, DataTypes) => {
  class RoleList extends Model {
    static associate(models) {      
      RoleList.belongsToMany(models.AccessList, {
        through: models.RolePermission,
        foreignKey: 'role_name',
      });   
    }
  }
  RoleList.init({
    name: DataTypes.STRING,
  }, {
    sequelize,
    modelName: 'RoleList',
    tableName: 'RoleLists',
  });
  RoleList.removeAttribute('id');
  return RoleList;
};
```

**permission-model.js**

```js
'use strict';
const {
  Model
} = require('sequelize');
module.exports = (sequelize, DataTypes) => {
  class AccessList extends Model {
    /**
     * Helper method for defining associations.
     * This method is not a part of Sequelize lifecycle.
     * The `models/index` file will call this method automatically.
     */
    static associate(models) {
      AccessList.belongsToMany(models.RoleList, {
        through: models.RolePermission,
        foreignKey: 'access_id'
      });
    }
  }
  AccessList.init({
    access: DataTypes.STRING,
  }, {
    sequelize,
    modelName: 'AccessList',
    tableName: 'AccessLists',
  });
  return AccessList;
};
```

**role-permission-model.js**

```js
'use strict';
const {
  Model
} = require('sequelize');
module.exports = (sequelize, DataTypes) => {
  class RolePermission extends Model {
    /**
     * Helper method for defining associations.
     * This method is not a part of Sequelize lifecycle.
     * The `models/index` file will call this method automatically.
     */
    static associate(models) {
    }
  }
  RolePermission.init({
    role_name: {
        type: DataTypes.STRING,
        onDelete: 'CASCADE',
        references: {
          model: "RoleLists",
          key: "name",
          as: 'role_name'
        }
      },
      access_id: {
        type: DataTypes.INTEGER,
        onDelete: 'CASCADE',
        references: {
          model: "AccessLists",
          key: "id"
        }
      },
  }, {
    sequelize,
    modelName: 'RolePermission',
    tableName: 'RolePermissions',
  });
  RolePermission.removeAttribute('id');
  return RolePermission;
};
```

Comment: Could it be `RoleList.removeAttribute('id');` ? Can you remove or comment this line and check again?

Comment: @Anatoly, thank you it's working. But I have added this to remove the id column from sequelize table will it work if I remove this line?

Comment: I tried your approach, but when I try to fetch data based on role, I am getting errors like this ```Unknown column 'RoleLists.id' in 'field list'``` query is ```AccessList.findAll({
        include: [
          {
            model: RoleList,
            as: 'RoleLists',
            attributes: ["name"],
            through: {
              attributes: ["access_id"],
              where: { role_name: usr?.role },
            },
          },
        ],
      });```

Answer (score 0):

First, you need to get rid of `removeAttribute('id')` calls.
Second, you didn't indicated that the `name` column of `RoleList` is a primary key column:

```js
RoleList.init({
    name: {
        allowNull: false,
        primaryKey: true,
        type: DataTypes.STRING,
   }
  }, {
    sequelize,
    modelName: 'RoleList',
    tableName: 'RoleLists',
  });
```